# Parse json into Dictionary with custom classes

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, deserialization

```
{
  "data" : {
                 "TTyTo3qHkFq8b-KsIHZOlQ" : {
                       "2016-05-01" : {
                             "value1" : 11,
                             "value2" : 87
                       },
                       "2016-05-02" : {
                             "value1" : 2,
                             "value2" : 34
                       }
                 }
    }
}
```

I have this json.
I can parse it into next object `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, int>>>`

How can I make from this object something like `Dictionary<string, CustomClass1>`, where

```
class CustomClass1 {
    DateTime Date {get;set;}
    Dictionary<string, int> Value {get;set;}
}
```

?

For deserealizing I'm using Json.NET.

Comment: what you posted is not valid JSON. Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Comment: @rufer7, small fix

Comment: What about `data` property, do you need to ignore it?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan, nope `data` should be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement custom [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) in order to achieve what you want.

First, you need to create `Root` class which will represent whole JSON:

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<CustomClass1>> Data { get; set; }
}

public class CustomClass1
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Please notice `Data`'s data type which is `Dictionary<string, List<CustomClass1>>` because you won't be able to deserialize into desired type: `Dictionary<string, CustomClass1>`

After that, you need to implement own custom `JsonConverter`:

```
public class CustomClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //Implement if needed
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = (JObject)JObject.ReadFrom(reader);

        var root = new Root();
        root.Data = new Dictionary<string, List<CustomClass1>>();

        JObject value = (JObject)obj.GetValue("data");
        foreach (JProperty prop1 in value.Properties())
        {
            var customObjects = new List<CustomClass1>();
            foreach (JProperty prop2 in prop1.Values())
            {
                var customObject = new CustomClass1();
                customObject.Date = DateTime.Parse(prop2.Name);
                customObject.Values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                foreach (JProperty prop3 in prop2.Values())
                {
                    customObject.Values.Add(prop3.Name, prop3.ToObject<int>());
                }
                customObjects.Add(customObject);
            }
            root.Data.Add(prop1.Name, customObjects);
        }

        return root;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type t)
    {
        return t.Equals(typeof(Root)); //Converter which handles only Root types
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

And finally pass it into `DeserializeObject` method overload:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, new CustomClassConverter());
```